# Android change windowBackground programmatically on application start

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm well conscious how to set the *splash* of an activity in Android using the theme in manifest and the tag *windowBackground*.

A client recently showed up asking to "change the splash screen accordingly to some events during the day". 
I'm almost sure that it cannot be done, but I decided to give it a shot with this code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        int random = (int) Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() % 3);

        switch (random) {

            case 0:
                setTheme(R.style.FullscreenTheme1);
                break;

            case 1:
                setTheme(R.style.FullscreenTheme2);
                break;

            default:
                setTheme(R.style.FullscreenTheme3);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this isn't working.

Someone already tried to accomplice this or has a better idea?

Thank you

EDIT:

Create a fake activity or fragment to show as splash screen will be easy, but will left that unpleasant white (or black depending on the theme) flash at the application start.

This question is about feasibility of changing the splash screen programmatically with the same result as hardcoding it up in the manifest.

Comment: Were you able to do this?

Comment: Sorry, seems to be impossible.
You can set the splash screen when your app starts but it's not changeable, as well described here: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/
Or you can create a View that works like it, if you can afford a half of a second of empty screen when opening the app, that you can change everytime you want.

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the Splash and simulate it by creating an Activity in fullscreen that shows your desired Image for n seconds?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly better/earlier place to select the theme would be in `onApplyThemeResource` (called before `onCreate`):

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void onApplyThemeResource(Resources.Theme theme, int resid,
        boolean first) {
        int random = (int) Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() % 3);

        int myRes;
        switch (random) {
            case 0:
                myRes = R.style.FullscreenTheme1;
                break;

            case 1:
                myRes = R.style.FullscreenTheme2;
                break;

            default:
                myRes = R.style.FullscreenTheme3;
                break;
        }
        super.onApplyThemeResource(theme, myRes, first);
    }
}
```

or Kotlin:

```
override fun onApplyThemeResource(theme: Resources.Theme, resid: Int, first: Boolean) {
    val myRes = when(System.currentTimeMillis() % 3) {
        0L -> R.style.FullscreenTheme1
        1L -> R.style.FullscreenTheme2
        else -> R.style.FullscreenTheme3
    }
    super.onApplyThemeResource(theme, myRes, first)
}
```

However, this doesn't solve the problem of the white/black flash at the application start.

Our way around this is to set a **neutral theme** (only background color, which is the same as the theme background in all the variations) as `android:theme` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and then switch to the right variation in `onApplyThemeResource`, which in our case is just some logos over the colored background.

Result: the app "flashes" a plain color background (instead of black/white, until Android has initialized the app), and then shows the logos on this background (depending on the state decided in `onApplyThemeResource`) while we do our app initialization.

This is not perfect, but for us it's good enough - maybe it helps someone else.

Answer (score -2):

Try this if you want to change just the background, the actionbar color and appearance can be done in much the same way.

```
    package com.example;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment {
        private LinearLayout mainLayout;

        //since you seem only interested in the background color changing, using a theme might seem to be overkill
        //that is if its for a very short time
        //but then a theme is better if you are concerned about branding
        //what i have here is basically to cahnge the background color
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);
mainLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
            colorList.add(R.color.accent);
            colorList.add(R.color.primary_light);
            colorList.add(R.color.secondary_light);
            colorList.add(R.color.secondary);
            colorList.add(R.color.secondary_dark);
            colorList.add(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
            colorList.add(R.color.primary_dark);
            colorList.add(R.color.primary);

            return v;
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> colorList = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           new CountDownTimer((1000 * 14), 1000) {//set my timer to 14 seconds, restarts if a certain condition is not met
           //set the timing to appropriate values or if you are just interested in a particular event do this in that section
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    //do update here
                    mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().
                            getColor(colorList.get((int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 7)));
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    if (!done)
                        this.start();
                }
            }.start();

            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

This should work for the current activity.

Comment: As I state in the _EDIT_ it's not the type o splash screen I'm looking forward.